# Getting TSV file output excluding 2 resource types from the az resource list in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I need to get the azure resource list from the azure CLI excluding 2 kinds of resource types and output the file to a TSV file. I was able do this via PowerShell from the following command.

PowerShell Command

```
get-azresource | where ResourceType -notmatch microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks | where ResourceType -notmatch microsoft.insights/actiongroups | export-csv C:\Users\7.csv
```

I need to get this result from Azure CLI excluding the mentioned resource types to TSV file (Since we cannot get the Azure CLI output in CSV)

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup the info for [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), where you can see it has a parameter `-Delimiter` you use to set a different character as field separator (in your case a TAB character) instead of the default *comma*.

To prevent an extra line on top of the output file with field type definitions, there is also a switch `-NoTypeInformation`

Then looking at your code I have some remarks:

- You use `-notmatch` which is a regex comparison operator, but the strings to compare against have characters that have special meaning in regex (most notably the dot)
- You seem to not use quotes anywhere and because your strings and output path do not contain spaces, in this case that is not a problem. However, I think it is a good habit to always use single quotes around such strings and paths

Try

```
# the resource types to exclude
$exclude = 'microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks', 'microsoft.insights/actiongroups'
# create a regex string from the $exclude array, where the elements are joined with the regex OR ('|')
$notThese = ($exclude | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -notmatch $notThese} | 
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\7.tsv' -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you very much, actually my requirement is to get the output via the Azure CLI by EXCLUDING mentioned resource types not from powershell. If you can help me I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: @AnonymousCorp Ah, I see. I'm not really familiar with that syntax, but perhaps something like this: `az resource list --query ([? type != "microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks"] && [? type != "microsoft.insights/actiongroups"]) --output tsv` ??

Comment: Thanks again for the kind concern. I got a similar command from another person, but still it not working. But the powershell command that I have mentioned here is working fine. The issues is with Azure CLI.

Comment: @AnonymousCorp Then how about `az resource list --query "[type != 'microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks' && type != 'microsoft.insights/actiongroups']" --output tsv` ?